# Does the pointwise convergence of a sequence of Taylor series imply the convergence of the coefficients?

Tags: calculus, taylor-expansion

For each fixed $n\in\mathbb N$, let $(a_k^{(n)})_{k\in\mathbb N\cup\{0\}}$ be a real sequence and let $(a_k)_{k\in\mathbb N\cup\{0\}}$ be another real sequence.

---

Suppose the following: there exists some $r>0$ such that the Taylor series:
\begin{align*}f_n(x)\equiv&\,\sum_{k=0}^{\infty}a_k^{(n)}x^k\quad\text{for each $n\in\mathbb N$,}\\f(x)\equiv&\,\sum_{k=0}^{\infty}a_k x^k\end{align*} all converge whenever $x\in[-r,r]$. (The formal power “$0^0$” is interpreted to be $1$.)

---

Suppose furthermore that $$\lim_{n\to\infty}f_n(x)=f(x)$$ pointwise for each $x\in[-r,r]$.

---

**Question:** Does it necessarily follow that the coefficients $$\lim_{n\to\infty}a_k^{(n)}=a_k$$ converge for each $k\in\mathbb N\cup\{0\}$? Any hints would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: You can't even guarantee $f$ will be continuous.

Comment: @AJY The limit function $f$ is continuous at least in the interior of the domain of convergence $(-r,r)$, because it is a power series.

Comment: This might might be trivial or it might help: If $1$ is in $[-r,r]$ and $f(1)$ exists then compute $f(1)$.

Comment: Consider $(\cos ( \pi x))^{2n}$. Converges to a function that gives $1$ on integers and $0$ elsewhere. Discontinuous at $0$.

Comment: @AJY I specifically _assume_ that $f$ is a power series _and_ it is a limit of a sequence of power series, all of these series having a common compact domain of convergence.

Comment: My apologies. Indeed you do.

Comment: Nice question ! (+1) Its complex and compactly convergent version has a positive answer due to Cauchy formula. To avoid painful unions note that $0\in \mathbb{N}$ (usual) see [here](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Natural_number) where it is said [Mathematicians use $\mathbf{N}$ or $\mathbb{N}$ to refer to the set of all natural numbers.]

Answer (score 1):

Set $f_n(x) = \frac{\sin (nx+n)}{n}$. Now $f_n \to 0$ pointwise. The derivatives are
$$
f'_n(x) = \cos (nx+n)\,,
$$
and thus the pointwise limits $\lim_{n \to \infty}f_n'(x)$ do not exist.

Assume that your claim is true. Now $f_n'(0) = a_1^{(n)}$ should converge to something...

Comment: Well the pointwise limit converges at $x=-1.$ Why not just concentrate on $x=0$?

Comment: @zhw. Yes it is true that $f_n'(-1)$ exists, I didn't notice that. But we could choose $r=1/2$ (triple_sec's notation). And my point was to concentrate on $x=0$. That's why I explicitly mentioned $f_n'(0)$.

Comment: Nice counterexample (+1)